# HTML Button Opening and Filling Out Other Page (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to open the Enrichr website (https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr/) and auto-fill a list of genes into the large box for genes. Here the variable "data" represents those genes. I have a button in my html code that executes the following function:

```
function myFunction()
   {
       var data = "hello";
       var OpenWindow =window.open("https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr/");
       OpenWindow.onload = function(){
           OpenWindow.document.getElementById("text-area").value = data;    
    }}
```

This code doesn't seem to work. It opens the webpage but does not fill anything out. I don't think the onload function is working properly.

Comment: Are you doing this from a page on the same webserver? If not, then cross-origin restrictions are going to get in your way.

Comment: You can use a Bookmarklet

Comment: I need this to function as a website for other users, so I don't think Bookmarklet would work.

Comment: @MikeBrockington I believe it is the same webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you want to change `OpenWindow.document.getElementById("text-area").value` before page load completly. Maybe try it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = "hello";
  var OpenWindow =window.open("https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr/");
  OpenWindow.onload = function () {
    OpenWindow.document.getElementById("text-area").value = data;   
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work either. I'm supposed to have OpenWindow.onload = function(){} within the larger myFunction() brackets right?

Comment: I've edited my post. I mean something like this. @InkoBovenzi

Comment: On further testing, it appears that the OpenWindow.onload line is never running. Any ideas as to why? @PouriaMoosavi